# A better way of switching between Android source versions

Tags: android, git, android-manifest, repository

I would like to be able to switch between various android releases (1.0, 1.5, 2.0, etc.) and then access them via the file system to copy all files for that version into a tarball. Currently I am just running `repo init -u <source URL> -b release-1.` to get each version (changing the tag for each version I need). 
If this was a single git, I could check out the branch/tag I needed and the prject directory would "morph" to reflect then and I could just tar that folder. since the android source is split into multiple git repositories controlled by repo I have not yet found a way to change this other then the method mentioned above.

any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you can run init -b {branch} on an existing checkout, without the -u parameter.
repo sync will change your sources to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just source for the IDE debug of application there is a blog post listed in one of my android-programming knols giving links to those source code archives.

just search for android-programming on the Google Knol site to find it..

Comment: Can't find it, could you please post a direct link? Thanks.